# Why doesn't the octal sequence '\0101' equal 65 decimal?

Tags: c, output

Consider this C program:

```
unsigned char c2 = '\0101';
printf("%c, %d\n", c2, c2);
```

I believe that the output should be: **A 65** but the actual output is **1 49**.

Reasoning: 0 as prefix in character constant declares it in octal format and octal value of 101 is 65. Then the ASCII value corresponding to 65 is A. Can someone tell me where I am going wrong? I tried the same code for hexadecimal as '\x41' and it gave the desired output.

Comment: I don't know if you notice btw, if you remove the 0 (\101), you get the desired output

Comment: @user3121023 Octal *escape* sequences. The octal literals don't have this restriction.

Comment: @AlexanderSantos Yeah it works, but then how do we specify that the input is octal ?

Comment: @Archer unsigned char c2 = 0101 works

Comment: but unsigned char c2 = x41 doesn't work @AlexanderSantos

Comment: Because the syntax is `0x41`

Comment: Note that in `'\xA74129'`, there are three bytes worth of hex; unlike octal, there is no limit on the number of hex characters that make up a hex escape `\xXXX`.  Nor is there a requirement that the number of characters  in a hex escape is even.  See C11 [§6.4.4.4 Character constants](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.4.4.4) where the one to three octal digits and unrestricted hex are both clearly specified.

Comment: Note that [¶11](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.4.4.4p11) states: _The value of an integer character constant containing more than one character (e.g., 'ab'), or containing a character or escape sequence that does not map to a single-byte execution character, is implementation-defined._

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The escape sequence for a character in octal format is a backslash followed by up to three digits, meaning the last digit is not part of the escape sequence.  This is specified in section 6.4.4.4p1 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) regarding "Character constants":

> ```
> octal-escape-sequence:
>   \ octal-digit
>   \ octal-digit  octal-digit
>   \ octal-digit  octal-digit  octal-digit
> ```

So `'\0101'` is actually a multi-byte character constant: the first is `\010` which is the value 8, and the second is the character `'1'`.

A leading `0` is used to specify a *numeric* octal constant, not a *character* octal constant, so you don't need the leading 0 in this case:

```
unsigned char c2 = '\101';
```

If you did want to use a numeric octal constant, you would do this:

```
unsigned char c2 = 0101;
```

Comment: See [§6.4.4.4 Character constants](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.4.4.4) for the standard specification.

Answer (score -1):

This `'\0101'` is a multibyte integer character constant. It has the type `int`. Its internal representation is implementation-defined. So internally it can be represented like

```
0x00000849
```

In this declaration

```
unsigned char c2 = '\0101';
```

the constant was truncated to `0x49` (the least significant byte) and is assigned to the variable `c2`.

So this value `0x49` is outputted as a character and as an integer in the `printf` call.